# AD tool for searching and manipulating

Tags: untagged

My company uses Micorosoft [Active Directory Application Mode](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2003/adam/default.mspx) in one of our applications. Some times i have to look inside to find if things are stored properly. So i have to be able to search and sometimes manipulate values in the AD.

I have found the [Sysinternals AD Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963907.aspx) and i think that is ok, but i was wondering if there are other tools, maybe better ones, out there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any LDAP capable tool can really do it. You could use ldp (in the WIndows support tools), or something like adfind from joeware.net.

Thanks,

Brian Desmond

Active Directory MVP

Comment: joeware has a ton of awesome tools, that are easily scriptable.

Answer (score 1):

The [PowerShell Community Extensions](http://pscx.codeplex.com/) (PSCX) includes a Directory Services provider, to map AD into PowerShell's drive model.

Answer (score 1):

[ADSI Edit](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc773354%28WS.10%29.aspx) looks pretty similar to AD Explorer, though it's probably not as good for connecting to ADAM (it tries to connect to your login server as soon as you load it).

JXplorer or Apache Directory Studio are what I'd recommend if you're after a more heavyweight tool.

Answer (score 1):

Check out Apache Directory Studio. Simple to use and powerful. Straightforward as well
http://directory.apache.org/studio/

Answer (score 1):

The [Microsoft Technet Script Center](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptcenter/bb410849) (and the [Repository](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter)) have metric gobs of Microsoft-submitted, and user-submitted scripts for doing anything and everything in AD, if you don't mind getting your hands dirty with a text editor.